# How do centralised and change the text to blue for my Display Time in PHP

Tags: php, html

currently, my code is this and I do not know how to make it centre and the text in blue.

```php
$date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Singapore') );      
$dateString =  $date->format('d-M-Y H:i A');
echo $dateString;
```

Below is a reference to what I'm referring to! sorry I'm very new to PHP
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SH9j.png)

Comment: Remember; PHP is server-side. You want preferably want to manipulate the frontend via CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to echo out the HTML you want:

```
echo "<span style='color: blue; text-align: center'>$dateString</span>"
```

If you have CSS class specified then you swap out the `style` attribute for a `class` and get the same effect.

```
 echo "<span class='some-class'>$dateString</span>"
```

Comment: `<span`> is an inline element and `text-align: center` might not be obviously visible. Use a block element like `<div>` instead to center the text.